# jQuery "on" blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my app;

```
inputFld.on("blur.typeahd", function(){alert(1)});
```

Now there is inputFld DOM element on my page

But I do not see any element with a class of "typeahd"

Still my code goes inside the function and I get alert 1

My question is if I am interpreting blur.typeahd incorrectly?
Is typeahd an element in this case or something else?

Comment: As far as i know .on() expects an event type and a callback, not some kind of css selector.

Comment: You should use the 'addClass' query function to add a class. 
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ 

However, are you saying if on blur, then add a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are getting it wrong.

here `blur.typeahd` stands for [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Comment: Thx a lot...So you are saying that I should look for event "typeahd" being triggered somewhere in my code...But I could not even find any typeahd event getting triggered in my code...

Comment: no, you it is the same as `blur` event, the namespace is used so that the creator can safely unregister only this event handler using `.off('blur.typeahd')`

Comment: @testndtv if you use `.off('blur')` then it will remove all `blur` event handlers associated with the elements which may not be what you want, you want to remove only this particular handler